# Как заставить регулярное выражение выбирать нужное значение при перечисление

Tags: javascript, jquery, регулярные-выражения

Так работает

```
/Charlie:\s(.+)/
```

А если начинаешь перечислять

```
/(Charlie|Jack|Oliver|Harry|Thomas):\s(.+)/
```

Находит только Charlie или Jack

Для примера при вставки

```
Charlie: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

или

```
Jack: bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
```

или

```
Oliver: vvvvvvvvvvvv
```

Сам код js https://jsbin.com/roweralemo/edit?html,js,output

```js
$(function(){


    $('#text').on('change keyup click', function(){
        var text = $(this).val();
        if (text.length<10) {return};


        if (/(Charlie|Jack|Oliver):\s/.test(text) && !$('#title').val().length) {
            var title = text.match(/(Charlie|Jack|Oliver):\s(.*)/)[1];
            $('#title').val(title).trigger('change');
        }


        });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>

<p>получаем результат, в этом поле aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<p>   
<input type="text" id="title"/>
<br><br><br>
<p>вставить сюда > Charlie: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<p>
<textarea style="width:200px;height:400px;" id="text"></textarea>
```

Результат на фото

[image: скриншот]

Comment: В примере у вас за именем двоеточие и дальше пробел, а в регулярке имя и за ним сразу пробел

Comment: @Tunker
Спасибо!  Опечатку исправил,но это ничего не меняет

Comment: Исправьте `[1]` на `[2]`: `var title = text.match(/(Charlie|Jack|Oliver):\s(.*)/)[2]`?

Comment: Не надо удалять вопрос после получения ответа.

Comment: @Qwertiy ♦ вопрос был удален так как не было ответа и разобрался сам.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew спасибо, как вариант!

Comment: @G-Force53, ответ уже был в момент удаления.

Comment: @Qwertiy ♦ Возможно его не увидел

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема в том, что у вас возвращается элемент первой группы, но когда вы добавляете новую группу, то она становится первой.
В регулярных выражения нумерация групп идет сначала выражения:

```txt
([...])(...(...))
^_____^___________первая группа
_______^________^_вторая группа
___________^___^__третья группа
```

Решением может быть - вывод нужной группы:

```js
const str = `Charlie: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa`;
const reg = /(Charlie|Jack|Oliver):\s(.*)/;
var res = str.match(reg);
console.log(`Это первая группа: ${res[1]}\nЭто вторая группа: ${res[2]}`);
```

Или же, перебор слов сделать в группе без захвата:

```
(?:Charlie|Jack|Oliver):\s(.*)
```